# Mail::to php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, controller, mailto

I am trying to send an email to a new registered user but for some reason the email is not being sent. I have the following:

**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{   
    $user = User::create([
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]); 
    Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new WelcomeMail($user));

    return $user;
}
```

**app/Mail/WelcomeMail.php**

```
class WelcomeMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /** 
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {   
        $this->user = $user;
    }   

    /** 
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {   
        return $this->view('emails.welcome');
    }   
}
```

**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/WelcomeController.php**

```
class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    /** 
     * Send Verification Email
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function sendEmail(Request $request)
    {   
        Mail::to($request->user())->send(new WelcomeMail($user));
    }   
}
```

And my `blade` is at `resources/views/emails/welcome.blade.php`.

I think I might be missing a route to activate the `WelcomeMail` controller?

I know the blade is fine because it works whenever I try to route it manually

```
Route::get('/mailable', function (Request $request) {
    $user = $request->user();

    return new App\Mail\WelcomeMail($user);
});
```

Any idea what might be the issue?

**EDIT**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=9d1204***
MAIL_PASSWORD=7919be***
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: Can you share your .env file too?

Comment: @PaulSantos Sure. Edited

Comment: do you have the `smtp` command installed in your system?
Have you tired with the `mail` command?

Comment: @LuigiT. I just ran `mail -s subject someone@example.com` from the command line and it worked.

Comment: What's in your logs?

Comment: @hogan no errors. User registration works and it just redirects to home page.

Comment: What do you have in your .env file in the line QUEUE_DRIVER and what is the 'default' in config/queue.php?

Comment: @hogan `QUEUE_DRIVER` I tried both `redis` and `sync`; `default` is  `env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync')`

Comment: when set to sync, try that action again and let me know if there are errors in your frontend and the laravel log file. Additionally, are you sure the RegisterController@create method is being called?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `QUEUE_DRIVER` value to `sync` in your .env and see if anything happens.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change the outcome. The new controller still doesn't run. Not sure if it is supposed to though, because I have the `Mail::to` in the `RegisterController`..